# I rest and sing and sing or help - What am I?

Tags: riddle

On my own or in a pair, I might rest quietly at your side.

In greater numbers we may hang and sing about your adventures.

More again and we might sing to a crowd, or perhapse help you give answer.

**What am I?**

Comment: If this is self made provide hints or it may lead to multiple possibilities.

Comment: @wrangler I could be wrong but I don't think there'll be any answers that will fit as well as the one I'm after.

Comment: @BrentHackers Is 'perhapse' a typo? Sorry to be pedantic :P

Comment: @Inazuma Probably.  I'll have to check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> Keys?

On my own or in a pair, I might rest quietly at your side.

> One or two keys might not jangle

In greater numbers we may hang and sing about your adventures.

> When you have a number of keys, it tells of all the doors you can open

More again and we might sing to a crowd, or perhapse help you give answer.

> Keys on a piano would sing to a crowd at a performance. Answer keys would give you an answer to a test, etc.

**OP Answer**

On my own or in a pair, I might rest quietly at your side.

> One or two keys may sit quietly in your pocket.

In greater numbers we may hang and sing about your adventures.

> A large number of keys would instead be worn on the belt where they will jingle as you walk.

More again and we might sing to a crowd, or perhapse help you give answer.

> Keys on a piano.  Keys on a computer keyboard.  :)

Comment: Oops didn't see  @abhinsit's answer..

Comment: Yep.  Not bad +1 but there is an answer that will fit all 3 clues.

Comment: Guessing again...but still think it's not a perfect fit...

Comment: Correct answer but you should really submit as a new answer next time.  I'll edit with my own explanations.

Comment: Oh. how do you do that? 0.o EDIT: Nvm I see it T_T

Answer (score 2):

May be:

> A secret

On my own or in a pair, I might rest quietly at your side.

> Can be a single or many secrets of a person. Until known they rest quietly on persons mind.

In greater numbers we may hang and sing about your adventures.

> Every secret has an adventure or story attached with it.

More again and we might sing to a crowd, or perhapse help you give answer.

> If any of them is out they are transmitted to whole crowd.

Comment: Not a bad fit +1 but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Audio Speakers. Speakers if not used are sitting quietly. + They can be single or multiple

In greater numbers we may hang and sing about your adventures.

> Speakers let you sing your adventures and use in parties for hang outs.

Comment: Hi.  This isn't the answer I'm looking for.  Please use spoiler formatting and give an explanation in future.  Welcome to puzzling!